# What does "cushion" mean in this context?

Tags: meaning-in-context

What does "cushion" mean in this context?

> 7’ | Phillips crosses from out wide. Pereira **cushions** a header into the path of Gallagher in the box, but he can’t get the ball out of his feet and it runs through for Guaita to collect.

[source](https://mobile.twitter.com/WBA/status/1370753265437130755)

Comment: I had 8 points, now I have zero. I have always thought this site had cheaters. Now, I can see it does. My answer is 100% spot on even if I have to say so myself, which, in this case, I do.

Answer (score 1):

It does have a specific meaning, as the site below attests:

> Football Language: Cushion This word is used both as a verb, to
> cushion the ball, an adjective, a cushioned header, and as a noun, to
> have a cushion. When used as a verb, to cushion, means to pass or
> shoot in a controlled, delicate way. The ball is passed to a player,
> who then guides or directs the ball, taking the speed off the pass or
> cross. We can use the adjective to describe this kind of shot, header
> or pass: **a cushioned header is a header with no force or power added,
> the player simply directs the ball skillfully into the net**.
>
> Here are some examples; the first is from a BBC match report: “Massey
> nodded home a cushioned header from Clarke to silence Elland Road
> after the interval”  (BBC April 2019).

[bolding mine]

[English through football](https://languagecaster.com/football-language-cushion/#:%7E:text=We%20can%20use%20the%20adjective,ball%20skillfully%20into%20the%20net).

Answer (score 0):

No special meaning, rather a bit of colourful language invented by the commentator. Pereira heads the ball *in the manner of a cushion*, i.e. gently, not aggressively.

Comment: This is simply not so. Sorry.

Answer (score -1):

> What does "cushion" mean in this context?

Imagine throwing a rubber ball at a wall. The ball will rebound at speed.

Now imagine throwing the same ball at a cushion. The ball will hit the cushion, it will not rebound.

This explains how to cushion a ball.

The cushioning can be done totally - in which case the ball will drop straight to the ground, or it can be done partly, in which case it will travel away at reduced speed.